# Is it possible to create an Android Wear app with react native

Tags: react-native, wear-os

I have had a play with react native creating ios apps but have not tried android yet. With android you also get 'android wear' for watches etc, will react native work creating apps for those devices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

React Native does not run on Android Wear at the current time, so you would have to do that code native.

Comment: Thanks Marcus for confirming that, I had a feeling that was the case since I could find no documentation to support that it would but wanted to make sure.

Comment: is it still not possible ? what about android tv, applce tv and apple watch with react-native ?

Comment: More info [can be found here](https://www.quora.com/Will-React-Native-be-capable-of-Apple-Watch-apps)

Comment: more information about react native for TV decices (android tv and apple tv) can be found [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv)

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can try [React native vanilla](https://github.com/pavjacko/renative)

Comment: I am unable to get it working using Renative(React native Vanilla). The app keeps crashing. If you have used it, can you share a running sample project?

Comment: @vijaykrishna I didnt used Renative before. I plan to use it for hobby project and I wasnt able to find any alternatives actually :(

Answer (score 1):

Github Project: https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity

### Installation

```bash
yarn add react-native-wear-connectivity
```

### How to create a WearOS app using react-native

- Create a new react-native app using the same name as your Mobile app.
  It is important to use the same name because both apps need to share the same package name (AndroidManifest, build.gradle, the project files) and applicationId (build.gradle).

```bash
npx react-native@latest init YourMobileAppName
```

- Add the following line to the new project AndroidManifest (file ):

```xml
<!-- this file is located at android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

- Create a new emulator of type [WearOS Large round](https://gist.github.com/assets/24992535/f6cb9f84-dc50-492b-963d-6d9e9396f451).
- Pair the Android emulator with the Wear OS emulator. Follow this [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/connect-phone).
- Start the metro server on port 8082 with `yarn start --port=8082`
- Build the project with `yarn android`, open the [react native dev menu](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) and change the bundle location to `your-ip:8082` (for ex. `192.168.18.2:8082`).
- Repeat the same steps for the Android Phone Emulator and use a different port (for ex. 8081).
- **Important Note**: Before publishing to Google Play, make sure that both apps are signed using the same key (instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/signed-apk-android))

You can now build the app with `yarn android`. JS fast-refresh and the other metro functionalities work without problem.

### API Documentation

#### Send Messages

```js
import { sendMessage } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

sendMessage({ text: 'Hello watch!' });
```

#### Receive Messages

```js
import { watchEvents } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

const unsubscribe = watchEvents.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('received message from watch', message);
});
```