# Can we use react-native to build android wear apps?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build Wear app using react native. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it working. I ran into a lot of exceptions and couldn't even get the app running. I am wondering if react-native can even be used to build an android wear app. Please help me with your experience.

Comment: When I googled "react native android wear" this was my first hit:

https://github.com/bevkoski/react-native-android-wear-demo

I have not tested it but it seems entirely possible.

Comment: Actually, wear app is not built using react-native in that project. That demo is actually a react-native app connecting to wear app (built in native Android code).

Comment: Possible duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926013/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-react-native

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, you can. Do check this React native vanilla examples it can be used to build like so many variants.

[Github example](https://github.com/pavjacko/renative)

Comment: I can't seem to get it running. Facing too many errors. Can you please share a link to sample project if you found any?

Comment: @vijaykrishna I would suggest following that documentation and few commands will get you to project example. I don't see what's stopping you. Can you share whats the error here.

Comment: I am getting this error

`2019-07-04 10:03:06.178 25440-25440/renative.helloworld.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: renative.helloworld.debug, PID: 25440
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{renative.helloworld.debug/renative.helloworld.debug.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: @vijaykrishna There will be an activity created with RN and in manifest check its theme and do change it to Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use react-native-vanilla anymore to build for WearOS.

- React Native works without issues with WearOS (tested on real device and simulator) https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-create-a-wearos-app-using-react-native
- It is very easy to connect the WearOS App with the Mobile App as explained at https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity?tab=readme-ov-file#example-of-implementation

The advantage of react-native-wear-connectivity are:

1. You use react-native for both Android Mobile and WearOS. You just write JavaScript. No need for native implementation
2. You can connect WearOS to Mobile via Bluetooth.

https://github.com/bevkoski/react-native-android-wear-demo is just a demo, you will have to copy their native implementation. The main issue is that they expect you to build the WearOS app using Jetpack Compose. You can not build WearOS app with Java, you need to use Jetpack Compose. You may have a Java Module for ReactNative and Jetpack Compose implementation for Wear OS. The library uses Google APIs that are deprecated, so you should not use it.

For iOS you can use [react-native-watch-connectivity](https://github.com/mtford90/react-native-watch-connectivity/tree/master).
The APIs are the same used from react-native-wear-connectivity, so it will be easy to work with that, but you need to build the iOS watch app using xcode.