# React native for Android Wear OS or Samsung Tizen OS

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to create apps for Android Wear OS or Samsung Tizen OS with React Native, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use react-native to build android wear apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975545/can-we-use-react-native-to-build-android-wear-apps)

Comment: Yes, totally. Thanks very much.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926013/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-react-native which has much more votes.