# Creating a smart watch supporting app using React-Native

Tags: react-native, wear-os, apple-watch, wearables

We are doing and R & D on smart watch support using React Native.
R & D scope is like connect to a smart watch through phone then trigger/vibrate the watch when event comes from socket in phone. So at that time we will be sending some particular message from phone to smart watch to initiate the vibration.

When searching for the same we came across this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926013/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-react-native) which says RN doesn't support smart watch(remember the post is from 2016)

In the same post it mention about ReactNative Vanilla which I totally don't understand

1. Is react-native vanila a npm package or is it a new domain like react-native

Then I came across this [GitHub](https://github.com/bevkoski/react-native-android-wear-demo) but this involves native side coding.

If anybody can give any insight into the same it would be helpful
Thanks in advance

Tried searching for the same and couldn't find anything useful

Comment: react-native-android-wear does not require native code. You just install the npm package, you can check our demo project on github. The native code is included in the library and you can build wearos and android app using javascript (react-native). No native code.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a React Native wearOS app https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-create-a-wearos-app-using-react-native
2. sendMessage from Mobile App to WearOS app https://github.com/fabOnReact/react-native-wear-connectivity?tab=readme-ov-file#api-documentation

Mobile device sends the message

```js
import { sendMessage } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

sendMessage({ text: 'Hello watch!' });
```

WearOS device receives the message

```js
import { watchEvents } from 'react-native-wear-connectivity';

const unsubscribe = watchEvents.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log('received message from watch', message);
});
```

3. When you receive the message, use `Vibration.vibrate()` React Native API to vibrate the wearOS device:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration

```js
Vibration.vibrate()
```

This is the RN Implementation of the Vibration Module https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/aff06a4f8542f13ea2ea18fde0ec73a99fef577b/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/vibration/VibrationModule.java#L14